# C# pass enum "name" and enum value to method

Tags: c#, struct, enums

I'm doing Einstein-Riddle in C# atm and stubled across a problem.
I'm trying to do it with enums.
I have a struct called House. In House there are enums like Nationality, Color, Animal, ...
I create every possible solution in House and want to delete things with the hints (in a separate method).

Hint #1: British lives in red house.
Now I have to pass Nationality as enum and Nationality.British as value & Color as enum and Color.Red as value.

How to do this? I just want to call my Method like -

`CheckLine(Nationality.British, Color.Red);`

but what to put in parameter-list:

`static void CheckLine( ? )`

---

Here's my struct and enums

```
public enum Nationalitaet { Däne, Brite, Deutscher, Norweger, Schwede };
   public enum Farbe { rot, blau, grün, weiß, gelb };
   public enum Zigarette { Dunhill, Marlboro, PallMall, Rothmans, Wingfield };
   public enum Tier { Pferd, Fisch, Katze, Vogel, Hund };
   public enum Getraenk { Wasser, Kaffee, Milch, Tee, Bier };

   struct Haus
   {
       public int HausNr { get; set; }
       public Nationalitaet Nationalitaet { get; set; }
       public Farbe Farbe { get; set; }
       public Zigarette Zigarette { get; set; }
       public Tier Tier { get; set; }
       public Getraenk Getraenk { get; set; }
   }
```

I've a List with all solutions (called solution)
in CheckLine there's

````
if (solution[i].Nationalitaet == Nationalitaet.British && solution[i].Farbe == Farbe.Red)       
        solution.RemoveAt(i)```
````

Comment: `CheckLine(Nationalitaet.British, Farbe.Red)`

Comment: and in the method, which parameters?
static void CheckLine( ? )

Comment: It is unclear what `CheckLine` is supposed to do.

Comment: I edited and wrote it on bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct signature would be:

```
static void CheckLine(Nationality nationality, Color color) { }
```

An enum type (e.g. `Nationality`) can be used just like any other type, similar to how you would use `int` or `string`.

The names of the parameters (`nationality`, `color`) are of course free to choose, but generally speaking the most appropriate name for them matches the name of the enum type itself.

*There is not enough information in the question to judge whether it should be `static` or not, or whether the method should or should not return a `void`. This answer only focuses on the input parameters of the method.*

Comment: But my problem is, that nationality and color are not passed, sometimes it is e.g. color and animal

Comment: @AutMai: Different types, different signatures. That is C# behaving as it should. Enums are not polymorphic.